# How can I perform a SQL-INSERT/UPDATE with a virtual column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-insert

In my oracle application I'm using three columns and connect them in my SQL query to a product number:

```
SELECT id_part1 || '.' || id_part2 || '.' || id_part3 as product_number
FROM table
```

But I'm having trouble performing any update or insert query because of the virtual column. How can i perform these operations so that the virtual column is dissected into the three original columns and each value is saved correctly.

Thanks a lot

Jack

Comment: You can't (more or less....) Modify the original columns.

Comment: I'm not trying to modify the original columns. I'm searching for a way of modifying the virtual column or the query, to insert the values into the three original columns. So that if the user enters f.e. the product number 30.01.20 the insert query shall insert 30 into col1, 01 into col2 and 20 into col3. Maybe now my problem is more clear :)

Comment: Have a triggers where you separate the different parts from each other, and update the original columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from the comments and the question that you have a concerned an ordinary string type column `product_number` which needs to be splitted into other columns by dots. Then you can add virtual columns as desired like below

```sql
ALTER TABLE t
ADD (
    id_part1 AS (REGEXP_SUBSTR(product_number,'[^.]+',1,1)),
    id_part2 AS (REGEXP_SUBSTR(product_number,'[^.]+',1,2)),
    id_part3 AS (REGEXP_SUBSTR(product_number,'[^.]+',1,3))
);
```

those newly added added columns will totally depend on the column `product_number` and won't take any extra space within the related segment, but only represent your logic to display.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a573f9dd7d66bf22c0d6c12da3fd5c82)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The column `product_number` doesn't exists in the table so you can't `UPDATE` nor `INSERT` it

But I think you can use a simple trick to bypass the problem, you can try to add a phisical column `product_number` to your table and then add a BEFORE UPDATE trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CalculatedColumnSplit
    BEFORE 
    INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   
BEGIN
    :new.id_part1 := regexp_substr(:new.product_number,'[^.]+', 1, 1);
    :new.id_part2 := regexp_substr(:new.product_number,'[^.]+', 1, 2);
    :new.id_part3 := regexp_substr(:new.product_number,'[^.]+', 1, 3);
    :new.product_number := NULL;
END;
```